# Swift 3: Dictionary from large arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3

I am working with two large arrays containing following data:

```
print(dataID[1]) // ["DataID123"]
print(dataAR[1]) // ["73.075584"]
```

I'd like to form a dictionary from the two arrays by:

```
    var arrayofDict = [String: AnyObject?]()
    for i in 0...csvDataID.count {
        if i < csvDataID.count {
            let key     = csvDataID[i]
            let value   = csvDataAG[i]
            arrayofDict[key] = value
        }
    }
```

But get following error:

```
Cannot subscript a value to '[String: AnyObject?]' with an index of 
type '[String]'
```

I also tried a few other approaches aswell resulting in the same error.

Could anyone help me and is there even a more efficient way to handle the arrays? 
Thanks!

Comment: Not related, but why is the value optional? That makes no sense at all. Assigning a `nil` value for a key removes the key.

Comment: `print(dataID[1]) // ["DataID123"]` so `dataID[1]` is an array with one object (a String). So `key` is a `[String]` (array of Strings) not a `String` (just a String). Also, don't you want to do `for i in 0..csvDataID.count -1` instead of testing each time `if i < csvDataID.count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let key     = csvDataID[i][0]
let value   = csvDataAG[i][0]
```

Explaination:

The log says that csvDataID[1] is an array: `["DataID123"]`

The same is for the second one.:`["73.075584"]`

So,

`let key     = csvDataID[i] // you set the key is array.`

That's why you can see this error.